# logstash: how to include input file line number

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, filebeat

I am trying to create a way to navigate my log files and the main features I need are:

1. search for strings inside log file (and returning line of occurrences).
2. pagination from line `x` to line `y`.

Now I was checking Logstash and it was looking great for my first feature (searching), but not so much for the second one. I was under the idea that I could somehow index the file line number along with the log information of each record, but I can't seem to find a way.

Is there somehow a Logstash Filter to do this? or a Filebeat processor? I can't make it work.

I was thinking that maybe I could create a way for all my processes to log into a database with processed information, but that's also kind of impossible (or very difficult) because the Log Handler also doesn't know what's the current log line.

At the end what I could do is, for serving a way to paginate my log file (through a service) would be to actually open it, navigate to a specific line and show it in a service which is not very optimal, as the file could be very big, and I am already indexing it into Elasticsearch (with Logstash).

My current configuration is very simple:

**Filebeat**

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- type: log
  paths:
    - /path/of/logs/*.log
output.logstash:
  hosts: ["localhost:5044"]
```

**Logstash**

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
        hosts => [ "localhost:9200" ]
    }
}
```

Right now for example I am getting an item like:

```
    {
      "beat": {
        "hostname": "my.local",
        "name": "my.local",
        "version": "6.2.2"
      },
      "@timestamp": "2018-02-26T04:25:16.832Z",
      "host": "my.local",
      "tags": [
        "beats_input_codec_plain_applied",
      ],
      "prospector": {
        "type": "log"
      },
      "@version": "1",
      "message": "2018-02-25 22:37:55 [mylibrary] INFO: this is an example log line",
      "source": "/path/of/logs/example.log",
      "offset": 1124
    }
```

If I could somehow include into that item a field like `line_number: 1`, would be great as I could use Elasticsearch filters to actually navigate through the whole logs.

---

**If you guys have ideas for different ways to store my logs (and navigate) please also let me know**

Comment: There is a github discussion about a similar request: https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/1037

Comment: Same for Logstash: https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/7

Comment: I am not sure what you are looking for, though. You know that to a certain degree Kibana can show you the events in a file. It won't give you a page by page kind of list where you can actually click on a page number, but using time frames you could theoretically look at an entire file.

Comment: Yeah I could query on a time range, but it would easier (and more reliable) to query on a line number range.

Comment: At this point I am not sure this would work. Logstash, Beats, Kibana all have the idea of events over time and that's basically the way things are ordered. Line numbers are more of a text editor kind of functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are the log files generated by you? Or can you change the log structure? Then you can add a counter as a prefix and filter it out with logstash.

For example for

```
12345 2018-02-25 22:37:55 [mylibrary] INFO: this is an example log line
```

your filter must look like this:

```
filter {
   grok {
     match => {"message" => "%{INT:count} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"
     overwrite => ["message"]
   }
}
```

New field "count" will be created. You can then possibly use it for your purposes.

Comment: The pattern should read like this: `"%{INT:count} %{GREEDYDATA:message}"`

Answer (score 1):

At this moment, I don't think there are any solutions here. Logstash, Beats, Kibana all have the idea of events over time and that's basically the way things are ordered. Line numbers are more of a text editor kind of functionality.

To a certain degree Kibana can show you the events in a file. It won't give you a page by page kind of list where you can actually click on a page number, but using time frames you could theoretically look at an entire file.

There are similar requests (enhancements) for [Beats](https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/1037) and [Logstash](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-file/issues/7).

Answer (score -1):

First let me give what is probably the main reason why Filebeat doesn't already have a line number field. When Filebeat resumes reading a file (like after a restart) it does an `fseek` to resume from the last recorded offset. If it had to report the line numbers it would either need to store this state in its registry or re-read the file and count newlines up to the offset.

If you want to offer a service that allows you to paginate through the logs that are backed by Elasticsearch you can use the [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html) API with a query for the file. You must [sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) the results by `@timestamp` and then by `offset`. Your service would use a scroll query to get the first page of results.

```
POST /filebeat-*/_search?scroll=1m
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "source": "/var/log/messages"
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "offset": "asc"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then to get all future pages you use the `scroll_id` returned from the first query.

```
POST  /_search/scroll
{
    "scroll" : "1m",
    "scroll_id" : "DnF1ZXJ5VGhlbkZldGNoBwAAAAAAPXDOFk12OEYw="
}
```

This will give you all log data for a given file name even tracking it across rotations. If line numbers are critical you could produce them synthetically by counting events starting with the first event that has `offset == 0`, but I avoid this because it's very error prone especially if you ever add any filtering or multiline grouping.